# How do I install Ubuntu on a particular existing partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, upgrade, uefi

Dell Vostro 2520 64-bit laptop
Ubuntu 22.04.1
Windows 10
wine3 (?)

This laptop dual-boots Windows and Ubuntu, and has a SATA hard disk and an optical drive. I installed a Windows `*.exe` file for map editing, and then double-clicked it to launch it, but got a message to install `wine3` for 32-bit. I executed

```
~$ sudo apt install wine3
```

but when I came back the terminal was scrolling with deletions of mainly `lib*` files. After it ran to completion I could not open `thunar`, `nemo`, and many other apps, and several `*.desktop` file icons were missing from the vertical menu at the side of the screen.

I downloaded an Ubuntu 22.04.4 `.iso` installation file and burnt it to a DVD. The laptop would not boot off this DVD.

**Problem 1:** How do I change the boot order so the laptop will try the DVD drive *first*? Function keys F2 and F12 offered a choice of OSs, e.g.

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu
Windows
UEFI Optical drive
```

How can I get a choice of drives as I am used to from previous laptops?

**Problem 2: ** Is there any way to do an upgrade from 22.04.**1** to 22.04.**4** to replace the deleted files but preserve all the user files, i.e. *not* a clean install?

Comment: I'd suggest performing some checks, you mention downloading Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS & burning it to DVD; DVD is *optical* media & not intended for installing any release of Ubuntu 20.10 or later, ie. not intended for 22.04, so it's not only ensuring you burnt it correctly - but use a thumb-drive or intended media. You also mention 22.04.4 upgrade?   Ubuntu 24.04.2 was recently announced that it's release date has been delayed, yet you want to upgrade to a product that's still more than a year into the future? (it's not 2024 yet, 24.04.4 uses the stack from 23.10 but it's not yet released!).

Comment: You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system and preserve user files, even have the *manually installed* packages (*where installed from Ubuntu repositories*) re-install automatically (*providing internet is available during install for download*), but you didn't mention if you're asking about Desktop or Server...  It's possible using desktop systems, but as server apps can use system directories for configs; they'll get lost (desktop apps store data in $HOME which isn't touched on *unclean* install).   Re-use your existing partitions without format, and the *repair* type of install is triggered

Comment: There is no `wine3` package in the Ubuntu repositories, nor in the upstream Wine repository. Perhaps you mean `wine32`? Or something else? The most common reason for any `wine` package to break your desktop is 1) Using the wrong version of Wine, and 2) Not reading the output that clearly lists the removals before agreeing to the change.

Comment: Problem 1 seems a BIOS issue, not an Ubuntu issue. Keep searching in your BIOS setup options. Ubuntu cannot change those.

Comment: Problem 2 does not exist, except for time-travellers: 22.04.4 does not exist yet, and is scheduled for release around August 2024. The Ubuntu download page currently (Jan 2023) offers 22.04.1. Anything you have that says 22.04.4 is a typo or other mistake.